# Inserción de datos en mysql en tabla con varios campos como clave primaria

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql (Versión del servidor: 5.0.67-community-nt) con varios campos como clave primaria. Cuando empiezo la inserción de datos desde un programa en vb.net me indica el siguiente error:

> Duplicate entry for key 2

Los primeros valores que estoy insertando comparten el mismo valor en 4 de los 6 campos de la clave primaria pero los otros dos campos son diferentes.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de que de este error?

Comment: Es por que solo puedes tener un Primary Key en una tabla ... segun tengo entendido

Comment: Puedes mostrar el diseño de tu tabla? y los valores que intentas introducir

Comment: Tienes algún valor por defecto para esas columnas?

Comment: A lo mejor y el query para insertar esta mal, podiras mostrarlo?

Comment: Lo correcto para este tipo de preguntas es que incluyas un [mcve]. Y de paso, esa versión de MySQL es viejísima. Sería bueno ponerse al día.

Comment: Deberias incluir un ejemplo al menos de la estructura de tu tabla y como intentas introducir los datos para poder ayudarte de manera efectiva...

Comment: Vale acabo de encontrar el error al mirar la estructura de la tabla e ir a copiarla aqui. El que me paso la estructura de la base de datos tenía marcada como clave única uno de los campos que formaban parte de la clave primaria y por eso me estaba dando error.Perdón por las molestias

Comment: @user7395552 deberías añadir tu solución ya que otro usuario puede pasar por el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en que uno de los campos que formaban la clave primaria también tenia añadida la condición que ese campo tenia que tener un valor único, por lo que no me dejaba meter más valores que aquellos que fueran diferentes al valor de esa columna. Una vez quitada esa condición me permitió insertar más valores que tuvieran ese valor.
Pongo un ejemplo 
Mi clave primaria estaba formada por los campos c1, c2 y c3 y el campo c2 tenia añadida la condición de ser único con lo que me permitía solo lo siguiente:

```
c1    c2    c3
1     1     1
1     2     1 
Pero no me permitía
c1    c2    c3
1     2     1
1     2     3
```

Una vez eliminada la condición de c2 ya me permitía añadir claves primarias con el mismo valor de c2.